# How to perform mathematical operations on the value of an existing dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a dictionary such as :

```py
 a = {1 : [1, 2, 5], 2: [5,3,1], 3 : [9,8,7]}
```

I need to perform the following transformations on dict1 :

```py
dict2[i] = dict1[i] * log2 (1/dict1[i])
```

I tried to perform the solution as given by some of you here, but it didn't work, please take a look

```py
import math
a = {1 : [1, 2, 5], 2: [5,3,1], 3 : [9,8,7]}


c = {k: int(v * math.log2(1/v)) for k, v in a.items()}
    
    
    
print(c)
```

Comment: But `list2` is empty at the start and all indexes will be out of range. Did you mean: `list2.append(list1[i] * (math.log2(1/list1[i])))`?

Comment: Why do any list conversion at all rather than just running through `k,v in dict1.items()`? (or even `i,(k,v) in enumerate(dict.items())` if you really need a positional index, which for dicts is a bit odd)

Comment: @quamrana yes, i meant that. however i am not able to convert the list2 into dictionary b    if anyone knows the solution, please help me urgently. I have a submission in the next 30 min

Comment: Is the expected output with the example input given in your question `{'first': -104.0419249893113, 'second': -147.20671786825557, 'third': -212.8771237954945}` ?

Comment: What should dictionary b look like in the end?

Comment: @juanpethes yes

Comment: Then @DarkKnight's answer is correct.

Comment: The question has been edited rendering previous answers useless. We now have no idea what the expected output should be from the modified input

Comment: @DarkKnight I was merely trying to replicate the process on an input dictionary which turned out to be the one I have described here. Please don't get angry, I myself had no clue how the input would be changing as I am working on a complicated model at the moment. If you can help, please do.

Comment: Please stabalize the question: there should be no reason why the **input** structure would change so drastically. Please add the expected output that corresponds to this input example -- literally.

Answer (score 1):

The question has changed from the original posting.

In the latest version of the question, the source dictionary's values are lists in which case the requirement is probably:

```
from math import log2

a = {1 : [1, 2, 5], 2: [5,3,1], 3 : [9,8,7]}

b = {k: [_v * log2(1/_v) for _v in v] for k, v in a.items()}

print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: [0.0, -2.0, -11.60964047443681], 2: [-11.60964047443681, -4.754887502163469, 0.0], 3: [-28.529325012980813, -24.0, -19.651484454403228]}
```

Comment: Note that `log(1/v) == -log(v)`